# Neo4j 2.1.2 incremental backup fails but full backup succeeds

Tags: neo4j, backup

We recently upgraded our database from 2.0.1 to 2.1.2 (Enterprise) using the explicit upgrade procedure.

When trying to take a backup post-upgrade, full backups succeed, but incremental backups fail.

When running this command the first time, it succeeds:

```
~/neo4j-enterprise-2.1.2/bin/neo4j-backup -from single://127.0.0.1 -to /mnt/backups/neo4j-test-backup
```

Running it a second time gives the following error:

```
Performing backup from '127.0.0.1'

00:18:44.907 [main] INFO  o.n.k.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase - No locking implementation specified, defaulting to 'forseti'
Transactions applied
Exception in thread "main" org.neo4j.consistency.ConsistencyCheckingError: Inconsistencies in transaction:
    Start[3,xid=GlobalId[NEOKERNL|2772027681176372421|40044|-1], BranchId[ 52 49 52 49 52 49 ],master=-1,me=-1,time=2014-06-23 23:56:53.637+0000/1403567813637,lastCommittedTxWhenTransactionStarted=752027]
    1PC[3, txId=752028, 2014-06-23 23:56:53.647+0000/1403567813647]
    ConsistencySummaryStatistics{
    Number of errors: 2
    Number of warnings: 0
    Number of inconsistent RELATIONSHIP records: 2
}
    at org.neo4j.consistency.checking.incremental.intercept.CheckingTransactionInterceptor.complete(CheckingTransactionInterceptor.java:181)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.LogEntryVisitorAdapter.apply(LogEntryVisitorAdapter.java:62)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.LogEntryVisitorAdapter.apply(LogEntryVisitorAdapter.java:28)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.command.LogFilter.endLog(LogFilter.java:87)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaLogicalLog.applyTransaction(XaLogicalLog.java:1120)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaResourceManager.applyCommittedTransaction(XaResourceManager.java:856)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaDataSource.applyCommittedTransaction(XaDataSource.java:246)
    at org.neo4j.com.ServerUtil.applyReceivedTransactions(ServerUtil.java:461)
    at org.neo4j.backup.BackupService.unpackResponse(BackupService.java:401)
    at org.neo4j.backup.BackupService.incrementalWithContext(BackupService.java:315)
    at org.neo4j.backup.BackupService.doIncrementalBackup(BackupService.java:257)
    at org.neo4j.backup.BackupService.doIncrementalBackup(BackupService.java:210)
    at org.neo4j.backup.BackupService.doIncrementalBackupOrFallbackToFull(BackupService.java:231)
    at org.neo4j.backup.BackupTool.doBackup(BackupTool.java:240)
    at org.neo4j.backup.BackupTool.run(BackupTool.java:168)
    at org.neo4j.backup.BackupTool.main(BackupTool.java:71)
```

Any help/workarounds are appreciated.

Update: The same behavior persists after upgrading to 2.1.3

Comment: try to apply a transaction that writes something (e.g. create a node, set a property) and check if incremental backup works afterwards.

Comment: This is a live system where new nodes are created at least every minute. So to answer your question: No, applying a write transaction did not fix incremental backup.

Comment: I also get this problem in 2.1.3.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please check again in the issue is resolved with 2.1.4? I darkly remember a resolved issue regarding incremental backups.

Comment: Upgrading to 2.1.5 fixed this issue for us. Thanks.